# I can't to get Geolocation on my real android phone. Emulator works good. Flutter. Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, position, geolocator, inputconnection

I use this code for get position:

```
`Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    List<Placemark> placemark =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    if (placemark.isNotEmpty) {
      print('GOOD REQUEST ${placemark[0]}');
    } else {
      print('ERRROR: empty PLACAMARK ${placemark[0]}');
    }`
```

But I can't to get it. Emulator work good. Emulator give me info and coordinates. I use Flutter in Android Studio.

In my console I see this information:

```
`W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27064): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection`
```

How can i repaier it? I think that it problem in my android phone. Last time was this problem after flutter upgrade but I had used "pub get" and "pub update" and it was working good. Now it don't work. Permission is good. I selected "whileInUse".